# Correcting a mistake in subdivision

Tags: modeling

In the [beginner episode, where he makes the second square, at around 1:57](https://youtu.be/4xLdisAvjx8?t=117) he shows his cube as being subdivided twice, but when I tried to repeat this action, it split the sides as well making it deform and not sculpt correctly.

What should I do?

Comment: At least include a link of the video you are talking about!

Comment: Who is "he"? Maybe a link to the video?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry!